# error while making killcounter minecraft java

Tags: java, minecraft

I want to make a killcounter in my plugin for minecraft although im having an error. here it is

```
@EventHandler 
    public void onKill(EntityDeathEvent e) {
        
        Player player = e.getPlayer()
        int kills = player.getStatistic(Statistic.PLAYER_KILLS);
        player.sendMessage("you have " + kills);
        
    }
```

the error is within the e.getPlayer it says: "The method getPlayer() is undefined for the type EntityDeathEvent"

how do i fix this and why is this happening :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code in your posted form doesn't even compile since you're lacking the `;` after `e.getPlayer()`.

I never programmed anything for minecraft, but I just took a look at the [docs](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/entity/EntityDeathEvent.html), and the Class `EntityDeathEvent` or any superclass of it doesn't contain the method `getPlayer()`, therfore you're getting the error.

You have to work with the given methods, in this case this should be `getEntity()` and `LivingEntity.getKiller()`:

```
LivingEntity entity = e.getEntity();
Player killer = entity.getKiller();
```

Comment: Still having an error.

```
@EventHandler 
 public void onKill(EntityDeathEvent e) {
  
  LivingEntity entity = e.getEntity();
  Player killer = e.getKiller();
  int kills = killer.getStatistic(Statistic.PLAYER_KILLS);
  killer.sendMessage("you have " + kills);
  
 }
```

its still on the same place, the error is The method getKiller() is undefined for the type EntityDeathEvent

Comment: Yeah, I made a typo and edited the question, had the wrong variable in the killer's assignment :S